# python urlopen 403 inspite of URL being accessible via browsers

Tags: python, urlopen

..Hi folks ..the following URL https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/equities/indices/historicalindices.jsp?toDate=30-06-2016&fromDate=29-06-2016&indexType=NIFTY%2050 works perfectly fine while being accessed via browser but my python code below keeps throwing a 403. I trapped the error message which says "access denied" but the funny thing is the explanation which reads - You don't have permission to access "http://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/equities/indices/historicalindices.jsp" on this server

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated !

Code inserted below (contents of INDEX file are just 2 lines "NIFTY 50" and "NIFTY MIDCAP 50")

```
    from urllib import urlencode
    import urllib2
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from datetime import datetime
    import csv
    import time
    import datetime

    arr = [1,3,5,10]
    url = "http://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/equities/indices/historicalindices.jsp"
    fo = open("options/multiyearreturn/INDEX_DATA.txt", "wb")

    def is_number(s):
        try:
            float(s)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

    with open('options/multiyearreturn/INDEX', 'rb') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in spamreader:
            print row
            # cant take today since it will load with a days lag
            ToDt = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            if datetime.datetime.now().weekday() == 5:
                ToDt = ToDt - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            elif datetime.datetime.now().weekday() == 6:
                ToDt = ToDt - datetime.timedelta(days=2)

            for x in range(len(arr)):
                frmDt1 = ToDt - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
                if frmDt1.weekday() == 5:
                     frmDt1 = frmDt1 -  datetime.timedelta(days=1)
                elif frmDt1.weekday() == 6:
                     frmDt1 = frmDt1 -  datetime.timedelta(days=2)

                values = {'indexType' : row[0], 'fromDate' : frmDt1.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"), 'toDate' : ToDt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"), "User-Agent" : "Magic Browser" }
                data = urlencode(values).replace('+','%20')
                req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
                print data
                try:
                    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
                except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
                    print e.fp.read()
                the_page = response.read()
                soup = BeautifulSoup( the_page )
                MFDTLS = soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'number'})
```

Comment: Include full working example, row[0] is not defined anywhere

Comment: Hi Danny .. have updated the post .. please check..also as pointed above the file "INDEX" that i am reading has only 2 lines "NIFTY 50" and "NIFTY MIDCAP 50" .. appreciate your help !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

just added this additional line in the headers

```
                hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
               'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'}
```

the "Accept" header did the trick for me. Appreciate help!